# Error "Could not find a part of the path" while setting attributes on an existing file

Tags: powershell

I wrote a powershell script to strip R/H/S attributes off all files in a specified set of root paths. The relevant code is:

```
$Mask = [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly.Value__ -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Hidden.Value__ -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::System.Value__
Get-ChildItem -Path $Paths -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ForEach-Object {
    $Value = $_.Attributes.value__
    if($Value -band $Mask) {
        $Value = $Value -band -bnot $Mask
        if($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess($_.FullName, "Set $([System.IO.FileAttributes] $Value)")) {
            $_.Attributes = $Value
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine, but when processing one very large folder structure, I got a few errors like this:

```
Exception setting "Attributes": "Could not find a part of the path 'XXXXXXXXXX'."
At YYYYYYYYYY\Grant-FullAccess.ps1:77 char:17
+                 $_.Attributes = $Value
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], SetValueInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExceptionWhenSetting
```

I find this strange because the `FileInfo` object being manipulated is guaranteed to exist, since it comes from a file search.

I can't give the file names because they are confidential, but I can say:

- they are 113-116 characters long
- the unique set of characters involved are `%()+-.0123456789ABCDEFGIKLNOPRSTUVWX`, none of which are illegal in a file name
- the `%` character is there due to URL-encoded spaces (`%20`)

Do you have any suggestions as to what may be causing this? I assume that if the full path was too long, or I didn't have write permissions to the file, then a more appropriate error would be thrown.

Comment: Are these UNC paths (\\server\share\restofpath) or local paths?

Comment: @mklement0: My intention is to process directories as well as files, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @mklement0: Re the long path prefix, I do now suspect it's a long path issue. I will try that today.

Comment: @Theo: The paths will always be on a local drive.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343413/45375), the **problem turned out to be an overly long path** (longer than the legacy limit of 259 chars.)

In addition to **enabling long-path support** via **Group Policy**, you can enable it **on a per-computer basis via the *registry*** as follows, which requires running with **elevation** (as admin):

```
# NOTE: Must be run elevated (as admin).
# Change will take effect in FUTURE sessions.
Set-ItemProperty HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled 1
```

<sup>Pass `0` to turn support *off*.</sup>

---

However, even **with long-path supported turned OFF** (as is invariably the case on pre-Windows 10 versions) it is possible to handle long paths:

- **In *Windows PowerShell*** (PowerShell up to version 5.1), you must **use the *long-path opt-in prefix*, `\\?\`**, as discussed below.
- In **PowerShell [Core] v6+**, no extra work is needed, because it ***always* supports long paths** - you neither need to turn on support system-wide nor do you need the long-path prefix discussed below.

  - **Caveat**: While you *may* use `\\?\` in PowerShell [Core] as well in principle, support for it is inconsistent as of v7.0.0-rc.2; see [GitHub issue #10805](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805).

**Important**: Prefix `\\?\` only works under the following conditions:

- The prefixed path must be a ***full* (absolute), normalized path** (must not contain `.` or `..` components).

  - E.g., `\\?\C:\path\to\foo.txt` works, but `\\?\.\foo.txt` does not.
  - Furthermore, **if the path is a *UNC* path**, the path requires a **different form**:

    - `\\?\UNC\<server>\<share>\...`;
    - E.g., `\\server1\share2` must be represented as `\\?\UNC\server1\share2`

Answer (score 0):

It did turn out to be a long path issue after all, despite the wording of the error messages. A simple `Get-ChildItem` search for the files produced the same errors. I finally tracked down the files mentioned in the error messages and measured their total path lengths. They were exceeding 260 characters.

I experimented with adding a `\\?\` prefix to the paths, but powershell doesn't seem to like that syntax.

Fortunately, the script is being used on Windows 2016, so I tried enabling [long path support](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jeremykuhne/2016/07/30/net-4-6-2-and-long-paths-on-windows-10/) in group policy. That made the whole problem go away.

Comment: `\\?\ ` does work with `Get-Item` / `Get-ChildItem`,  but only with full, normalized paths. In PowerShell Core they additionally only work if you use `-LiteralPath`, unfortunately - please see my answer. It's curious that you originally got an error in `$_.Attributes = $Value`, without an explicit path argument; that would almost suggest a bug in the `.Attributes` property implementation, but I could not recreate that.