# powershell : find subdirectories with the longest paths

Tags: powershell, filesystems

I would like to find the longest paths among the subdirectories in a given directory, because I ran into this error:

```
The specified path, file name, or both are too long.
The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, 
and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

This is what I've tried:

```
$dir = "\\share\server\toto" 
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -Directory | 
Select-Object Name,FullName,
@{Name='FileCount';Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Recurse| Measure-Object).Count}} `
| Format-List *
```

but that gives me *all* directories.

Instead, I want to find the top 5 directories with the longest paths.

Answer (score 4):

This returns the 5 directories with the longest paths:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -Directory | % { $_.FullName } | Sort-Object { $_.Length } -Descending | Select -first 5
```

Comment: That works, but note that you're sorting and outputting path _strings_, not the directory-info objects as in the question. To get the latter, use `Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -Directory | Sort-Object { $_.FullName.Length } -Descending | Select -first 5`, but note that in Windows PowerShell, with long-path support not enabled in Windows 10, as suggested by the error message in the question, this won't solve the problem if the longest paths are actually longer than the legacy limit of 259 / 247 chars. for files / dirs., because `Get-ChildItem` will only find those with the "\\?\"-prefix.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that **long-path support<sup>[1]</sup> isn't enabled on your system** - on Windows 10, you can now enable it system-wide for .NET Framework v4.6.2+ based applications - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418901/45375).

**With long-path support *disabled*, `Get-ChildItem` (and `Get-Item`) won't find files and directories with too-long filenames in *Windows PowerShell*.**

By contrast, *PowerShell [Core] v6+* has long-path support enabled by default, and no extra work is needed - that is, your problem would not even have surfaced there.

In Windows PowerShell, to find too-long paths with long-path support disabled, you'll have to **prepend the *long-path opt-in prefix* to the *full*, literal, normalized target path**:

- For ***local* paths**, that prefix is **`\\?\`**; e.g., `'\\?\C:\temp'`
- For ***UNC* paths**, the prefix is  **`\\?\UNC\`**, with the **first `\` removed from the UNC path**; e.g, `'\\?\UNC\share\server\toto'`

**The following command finds all subdirectory paths that are too long (irrespective of how many there are)**, sorted by path length in descending order:

```
# $dir = ...  # set the target dir.

# Construct the long-path-opt-in form of the path (covers both local and UNC paths).
$dirLongPaths = ('\\?\' + (Convert-Path $dir)) -replace '^(\\\\[?]\\)\\\\', '$1UNC\'

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dirLongPaths -Recurse -Directory | 
  Where-Object { $_.FullName.Length -ge 248 } |
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property { $_.FullName.Length } | 
      Select-Object -Property Name, FullName, @{
        Name='FileCount';
        Expression = {(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File -Recurse).Count}
      } | Format-List
```

<sup>Note that I've streamlined the `Expression` script block by simply accessing `.Count` directly on the `Get-ChildItem` call's result.</sup>

Note the `Sort-Object` call, which sorts in descending order (`-Descending`) by calculated property `{ $_.FullName.Length }`, i.e., by the length of each input directory-info object's full path (`.FullName`)

Also note that the `\\?\` prefix is *not* also applied to the *nested* `Get-ChildItem` call, because the first call outputs directory-info objects whose `.FullName` property already *includes* the prefix.

---

<sup>[1] Historically, filesystem paths were limited to `259` chars. overall and to `247` chars. for the the directory part of a file path. By default, these limitations are still enforced for the sake of backward compatibility, even though the underlying APIs are no longer bound by these limits. Systems / applications can remove these restrictions by way of an *opt-in* mechanism.</sup>

Comment: @lockceee: What is your PowerShell version, and what Windows version is the server running on which the network share is located (I think the server must be running Windows)? What does `$dirLongPaths`  contain after you run my code? Do you get output with just `Get-ChildItem $dir`?

Comment: the share server is connected on Y:, I replace my varaible dir, $dir="Y:\"
I have got the same error like above

Comment: You mean _no_ output at all? Does `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dirLongPaths` produce output?

Comment: i try this code :
$dir = "\\share\\server$" 
$dirLongPaths = ('\\?\' + (Convert-Path $dir)) -replace '^(\\\\[?]\\)\\\\', '$1UNC\'
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dirLongPaths
and I get an error : Get-ChildItem : Illegal characters in path.
At line:3 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $dirLongPaths

Comment: Your `$dir` value has too many `\ ` chars.: it should be: `$dir = '\\share\server$'` However, that doesn't explain the problem. What is the actual, verbatim content of the `$dirLongPaths` variable when you pass it to `Get-ChildItem`?

Comment: Adapt the following value directly, and see if you still get the same error: `$dirLongPaths = '\\?\UNC\share\server$'`