# Docker image build "Access is denied” error on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, firebase, docker

I'm trying to build a node docker image for an application using Firebase and React on Windows 10, but it's giving me the following error:

```
> docker build -t projectName .
[+] Building 15.5s (6/8)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 31B                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:latest                                                                                                 11.0s 
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                     0.0s 
 => ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                                                                         4.3s 
 => => transferring context: 102.71MB                                                                                                                           4.3s 
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/node:latest@sha256:ca6daf1543242acb0ca59ff425509eab7defb9452f6ae07c156893db06c7a9a4                                     0.0s 
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error from sender: open functions\node_modules\google-gax\protos\google\iam\v1\logging: Access is denied.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
COPY . .
RUN npm install
CMD npm run start
```

I've tried different node versions, pulling the image and then building it again, but it doesn't seem to fix the error.
This is the first time I'm using docker (other than the getting-started tutorial, which worked), so please let me know if there's anything I need to add! Any ideas?

Comment: The error indicates that the client (docker CLI) which sends the files in your build context (current directory) to the build-daemon does not have access/permissions to read `functions\node_modules\google-gax\protos\google\iam\v1\logging`. Check if the user that runs the CLI has permissions to access that file / files in that directory.

Comment: Yep, turns out the file was corrupted and inaccessible due to some OneDrive pairing complications, thank you for steering me in the right direction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [theJeztah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230510/docker-image-build-access-is-denied-error-on-windows-10#comment120589034_68230510) has pointed it out, the build-daemon can't access `functions\node_modules\google-gax\protos\google\iam\v1\logging`.

This can also happen if your file paths are too long. In my case I have solved it by moving the folder to a directory with a shorter path.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841491/13940556) provides a powershell command to find long paths:
`Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse -Directory | % { $_.FullName } | Sort-Object { $_.Length } -Descending | Select -first 5`

Comment: Wow, this was exactly my issue.  My paths were too long by just a few characters.  I renamed my two folders and moved them to the root, then it all worked.  I wish they had a better error message for this.  I spent so long looking into windows permissions.

Comment: Me too—I simply renamed one file with a shorter name and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have this error and I just updated the Docker to the latest version and resolved this issue.