# Twilio python library causing docker build to fail

Tags: docker, twilio

I have created a Flask API that utilizes Twilio. When I build the Docker image from my Dockerfile, I get an error with this message:
***=> ERROR [internal] load build context***

And this

```
error from sender: open venv\Lib\site-packages\twilio\rest\notify\__pycache__: Access is denied/*
```

My **requirements.txt** file is using **twilio==7.9.3**

If anyone has any idea how to fix this, then I would appreciate it.

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile in your question?

Comment: A bit of searching shows that [Docker can have problem with the length of file paths on WIndows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70041710/28376). Could that be your problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual environments are very specific to the filesystem location and Python version they were originally built with.  In a Docker context, you wouldn't typically copy a virtual environment into an image (and you frequently don't use a virtual environment at all).

Next to your Dockerfile, create a file named [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) if you don't already have one, and make sure it has the line

```
venv
```

This will prevent the virtual environment from being sent as part of Docker's build context and so it won't get `COPY`ed into your image.

The flip side of this is that you do need to make sure Python packages are installed into your image.  This is frequently done using `pip`, something like

```bash
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This installs them into the "system" Python, but it's isolated inside a Docker image, so it doesn't interfere with other Python installations or other applications beyond the single thing packaged in the image.