# Powershell Error Message - Object Not Found

Tags: powershell

I receive the error message below in PowerShell (multiple times) when I attempt to scan a shared drive.  I read (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3259) that long path names will not work.  This particular path I reference below had 264 characters.

Is there a work around?

```
ERROR MESSAGE:
Get-ChildItem : Could not find item \\[server_name]\trans_bus_cntrls$\Continuous_Auditing_Technology\Automation Projects\Robotics Process Automation\Training Files 2019B\Training Required Files\AA Example Task Files\Example Exception Handling Example\Exception Handling Example.docx.
At line:1 char:17
+ ... get_files = Get-ChildItem \\[server_name] ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\ausdsrr208.au...ng Example.docx:String) [Get-ChildItem], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: If your path contains literal `[` and you have no variables to substitute, then use single quotes and the `-LiteralPath` parameter.

Comment: If the length of the path is the problem, the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418901/45375) should help. Let us know if it doesn't (with additional details).

Comment: Good advice in general, @AdminOfThings, but if the problem were unintentional interpretation as a wildcard pattern, there would be no output rather than an error message.

Comment: Regarding long path support in general, @Matthew. In Windows PowerShell it can be enabled, and always works with the `\\?\ ` prefix; in PowerShell [Core] 6+, it works _by default_ (_without_ the prefix; use of the prefix actually mostly does _not_ work - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805#issue-507972241).