# Opening explorer and selecting a file (with a long file path) through cmd or powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

I'm trying to use powershell (or cmd) to open a directory and select a file (or a directory).

The /select explorer command doesn't seem to work with long file paths:

```
explorer.exe /select,\\?\filepath
```

I've tried multiple combinations (the whole filepath in quotes, without the `\\?\` prefix, etc). And nothing seems to work. It just opens the default "This PC" location.

I know in powershell I can use:

```
ii filepath
```

But that doesn't solve the problem, as the `ii` command opens the destination folder/file rather than opening the parent and selecting said folder/file.

I would really appreciate the help.

(NOTE: I'm launching cmd/powershell through a C# script, .NET Framework 4.7.2. So if there's maybe a way to do it in C# without cmd/powershell, I'd be happy to use that solution)

Comment: What happens if you use 8.3 paths and filenames? eg 'PROGRA~1' for 'Program Files'. You can see the 8.3 namings with `dir /-n` in a command prompt

Comment: @Jonathan: the filepaths in question don't seem to fall inside the 8.3 paths listed by that command prompt (it's a custom directory).

Comment: @IbramReda: I don't think that'll do what I'm looking for. The functionality of my application in question is: I have a WPF app that lists some files. I right click the file in and want the functionality to "show file in explorer". So I want to open up an Explorer window with said file selected (without opening the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caveats**:

- The following solution **works only on volumes where [short (8.3) file names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#short-vs-long-names) are enabled** - **they are by default, but the feature can be *turned off*** , via the `fsutil.exe` utility's [`8dot3name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fsutil-8dot3name) subcommand, either system-wide or on a per-volume basis.

  - To query a given volume's support, run the following from an *elevated* session, using `C:` as an example:

    - `fsutil 8dot3name query C:`
- It is unclear to me how the above relates to *UNC* paths. Also, I presume, even the short version of a path can hypothetically exceed the overall path length limit of 259 characters, if the path is very deeply nested.
- At the file-system *API* level you can configure a system to support paths longer than 259 characters *by default*, without requiring the long-path opt-in prefix `\\?\`. This can be achieved via Group Policy or the registry - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418901/45375) for more information.

  - Unfortunately, even with default long-path support enabled, `explore.exe` apparently does *not* support paths longer than 259 characters.

---

I think [Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190042/jonathan) gave the crucial pointer: **Pass the *short* (8.3) version of the file path to work around `explore.exe`'s seeming non-support for paths longer than 259 characters.**

```sh
# Create a sample file with a long path (longer than 259 chars.)
$longFilePath = (New-Item -Force ("\\?\$HOME\_tmp" + 'x' * 250)).FullName

# Obtain the short (8.3) version of the long path.
# Note: Be sure to pass a FULL (absolute) path, which must be prefixed with '\\?\', 
#       unless default long-path support is enabled system-wide (see below).
$shortPathVersion =
  (New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFile($longFilePath).ShortPath

# Pass the short version of the path to explorer.exe
explorer.exe /select,$shortPathVersion
```

Run `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $longFilePath` to clean up the sample file later.

Note:

- In *Windows PowerShell* - unless default long-path support is enabled system-wide - you need to use the `\\?\` prefix for long paths (paths whose length exceeds `259` characters), as shown in the `New-Item` call above.

  - In *PowerShell (Core) 7+* this prefix is no longer necessary - it has long-path support *built in*; in fact, as of PowerShell 7.2 there are *bugs* that situationally prevent its use (which is problematic if your code needs to run in *both* PowerShell editions) - see [GitHub issue #10805](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10805)
- Unless default long-path support is enabled, the path passed to `(New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject).GetFile()` needs the `\\?\` prefix too - even calling from PowerShell (Core) 7+

  - Curiously, the short version of the path returned *retains* this prefix, but `explorer.exe` doesn't seem to have a problem with that.
- Even though `,` is normally a *metacharacter* in PowerShell (array constructor), when calling *external programs*, such as `explorer.exe`, it does *not* act as such, so there is no strict need to pass the arguments as `"/select,$shortPathVersion"` or `` /select`,$shortPathVersion ``

Comment: Hmm, so I tried your code, replacing $longFilePath with `$longFilePath = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]("filepath")`

And echoed both the long file path's full name and the short path version.
In my first test I put in "filepath" a path that was one directory before the long path, and both the long and short paths printed the same. But it did open explorer and pointed at it correctly (as expected).

But as soon as I put a long path in "filepath", it stopped working. Again, I tried with and without the `\\?\` prefix, and it just opened an explorer window pointing to "This PC".

Comment: @kirgod, note that `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo] "filepath"` generally doesn't work with _relative_ paths (because .NET and PowerShell have separate working dirs.) -and in Windows PowerShell only works if the full path is additionally `\\?\ ` prefixed. Please try my updated code (and explanation), which should now work in Windows PowerShell too. If it works for you, you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: What if 8.3 file names are disabled?

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer now. After plenty of testing, it works on my C drive but for some reason doesn't work if the same path is on the D drive. Both drives are NTFS.
On the D drive it creates the file fine, but both longFilePath and shortPathVersion look the same when echoed (and then the "/select" command again opens pointing at "This PC").
Not really sure what it could be, maybe there's a setting somewhere that the C drive has and the D drive doesn't?

Comment: @aschipfl, please see the caveats I've added to the top of the answer. I you have further information, please share.

Comment: Thanks, @kirgod. Please see the caveats I've added to the top of the answer, which clarifies that short file names may be turned _off_ either system-wide or on a per-volume basis. To test support for them on your D: drive, open an _elevated_ session and run `fsutil 8dot3name query D:`