# PowerShell copy-item does not copy subfolders that are beyond 7th in the tree

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to create a script using PowerShell to copy all files from folders and subfolders (recurse) based on the current location of the script file. The files are copied to specific folders named after the extensions of the files (E.g. .xlsx files will be copied to a folder named .xlsx). The script creates these folders if they don't exist. I've also provided an option to turn on -recurse. The challenge occurs when -recurse is performed. I have certain files that are buried within 8 to 10 layers of subfolders. The script throws an error when trying to copy these files and the error says the path does not exist (see below). Is there a limit to the number of folders that can be accessed through -recurse? If yes, is there a workaround for this problem? Please see the code below. I'm curious to find out the issue, any help on this topic is appreciated.

Exact error -
Copy-Item : Cannot find path "path of the file" because
it does not exist.

````
$Mypath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path 
$Mypath = Split-Path $Mypath -Parent
$FilePathName = $Mypath + "\test.txt"
$scriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name

$Allfiles = Read-Host -Prompt “Do you want to organize all files from subfolders as well? type - Yes/ No”

if ($Allfiles -eq "Yes") {
    $recurse = $True
} else {
    $recurse = $False
}

function createFolder ($Iterate, $folderPath) {
    
    foreach ($Iteration in $Iterate) {
       $FileExtn = $Iteration.extension
       $FileFullName = $Iteration.fullname
       $FullNameExtn = $folderPath + "\" + $FileExtn
       $checkFolder = Test-Path -Path $FullNameExtn
       if ($checkFolder -eq $False) {
           $checkIfFldr = (Get-Item $FileFullName) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
           if ($checkIfFldr -eq $False) {
               New-Item -Path $folderPath -Name $Iteration.extension -ItemType "directory"
            }   
        }
    }
}


function copyItem ($Iterate, [string]$Destination) {
    foreach ($Iteration in $Iterate) {
        $FileFullName = $Iteration.fullname
        $FileExtn = $Iteration.extension
        $checkIfFldr = (Get-Item $FileFullName) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
        $DestPath = $Destination + "\" + $FileExtn
        if($checkIfFldr -eq $False) {
            $FileParent = split-path -path $FileFullName -Parent
            $FileLeaf = Split-Path -Path $FileParent -Leaf
            if($FileLeaf -notlike ".*") {
                 Copy-Item $FileFullName -Destination $DestPath
            }             
        }
    }
}


function organizeFiles ([string]$filePath, [boolean]$GetAllFiles) {
    if ($GetAllFiles -eq $True) {
        
        $ListofFiles = Get-ChildItem $filePath -Recurse 
        createFolder $ListofFiles $filePath
        copyItem -Iterate $ListofFiles -Destination $filePath 
        
    
    } else {
        
        $ListofFiles = Get-ChildItem $filePath
        createFolder $ListofFiles $filePath
        copyItem -Iterate $ListofFiles -Destination $filePath   
    }
}

organizeFiles -filePath $Mypath -GetAllFiles $recurse

Read-Host -Prompt “Files organized by file formats successfully! Press Enter to exit”```
````

Comment: You're probably running into the 259-character path-length limit. Try using the `-LiteralPath` parameter consistently and prefixing your full paths with `\\?\` (sic). Alternatively, enable long-path support - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418901/45375).

Comment: @mklement0 Absolutely. The problem was the 259 character limit. I was able to bypass it by adding "\\?\" to $mypath. Thank you for your prompt response, much appreciated.