# PowerShell Batch rename.item $_ fails, "Could not find item"

Tags: powershell, batch-rename, rename-item-cmdlet, long-path

I'm trying out a rename-item command I found on YouTube to remove leading underscores in some very long file names, but I get a "Could not find item" error and no net changes.

Here's the initial command:

```
get-childitem *jpg | foreach {rename-item $_ $_.name.replace("__","")}
```

And here's the response in PowerShell:

[image]

The hoped-for result was a folder full of renamed JPG files with the leading __ underscore characters removed from the file names.

I'm not sure if PowerShell has trouble handling double underscores, if the file path + name is too long, or if there's a format error in the command. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Try with `Get-ChildItem -Filter *__*.jpg | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace("__","") }` instead

Comment: Let the pipeline take care of binding the file path: `Get-ChildItem *jpg |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("__","")}`

Answer (score 0):

- Indeed, as the comments point out, it is both more robust and more efficient  to pipe *directly* to [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) and to use a [delay-bind script block](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to determine the new file name.
- However, in your case the primary problem seems to be that the *file's path is too long*:

  - In *Windows PowerShell*, you need the long-path support opt-in prefix (`\\?\`) to target paths that exceed 259 characters in length.

    - The alternative is to *configure your system* to support long paths by default - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418901/45375) for details.
    - In the absence of long-path support, the error message you get is *misleading*, as it mistakenly suggests that an offending file *doesn't exist* (and, ironically, *prints its full path* as part of the error message).
  - Note that this no longer necessary in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), which unconditionally enables this support for itself.

Therefore, use the following, which explicitly targets the current location (directory) via the [automatic `$PWD` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pwd) and prepends `\\?\`, and also uses the delay-bind script-block technique.

```
# NOTE: The \\?\ workaround is no longer needed in PowerShell 7+
Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\$($PWD.ProviderPath)" -Filter *jpg | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('__', '') }
```

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate the suggestions but they haven't worked. I no longer get an error message in PowerShell, just a next-line prompt indicating success... but the filenames are unaffected. I tried both expressions, with \\?\$($PWD.ProverPath) and just Get-ChildItem *jpg |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("__","")}. No change either way.

Comment: Here's the expressions I copy-pasted into the PowerShell window:

FIRST: Get-ChildItem *jpg | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("__","")}

SECOND: Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\$($PWD.ProviderPath)" -Filter *jpg | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.replace('__', '') }

Comment: @BrianCurtis, I have no explanation - when I try the solution, it works for me. You  definitely need the ``\\?\`` prefix at least for the file shown in your question, and given that `Get-ChildItem` is what triggered the error, it should still occur when you try `Get-ChildItem *jpg |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("__","")}`, so something doesn't add up here. Does ``Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\$($PWD.ProviderPath)" -Filter *jpg`` list the files you want to rename?

Comment: @BrianCurtis formatting in comments has inherent limitations, and is only ever single-line. The following comment summarizes the capabilities:

Comment: As for formatting in comments: see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - in short: you can only use _inline_ code formatting (`\`...\``) with no support for line breaks. Unlike in posts, there must be _no whitespace_ after the opening and before the closing delimiter. _Multi_-`\`` delimiters for support of embedded `\`` chars. are supported (e.g. `\`\`"\`n"\`\``). Unlike in posts, ``\`` can alternatively be used to escape `\``, which, due to the no-whitespace requirement, is a must if you want to produce something like `\`enclosed\``. To produce a formatted ``\`` alone, use `\`\`\\`\``

Comment: P.S., @BrianCurtis: It may just be a formatting artifact, but the "SECOND" command in your previous comment suggest the following _no-op_: `replace('', '')`

Comment: No, the PowerShell window doesn't list any files. It just skips to the next prompt. Looks like I can't batch-rename after all. Thanks for trying!

Comment: @BrianCurtis, that is mysterious. Are you on a version of Windows PowerShell older than 5.1? What if you add the `-WhatIf` switch to the `Rename-Item` call, which _previews_ the operation? If it doesn't even _list_ files (if you omit the `Rename-Item` call), then perhaps you're in the wrong directory?

Comment: PSVersion is 5.1.22621.2506. I'm accessing it through Win Explorer with a shift-right-click "Open in PowerShell" command, and it shows the current folder path in the prompt. See Answer #2 for a screenshot.

Comment: @BrianCurtis, so it's not the PowerShell version. It's virtually impossible to troubleshoot your issue from afar beyond the pointers I've already given. You need to narrow down the problem step by step: Are you in the right directory? If you just _list_ files, do the ones you expect to see show up? Does using `-LiteralPath "\\?\$($PWD.ProviderPath)"` vs. not using it with `Get-ChildItem` make a difference? It should, if there are files with too-long paths.  Once the files of interest are getting _listed_, add the `Rename-Item` call with `-WhatIf` to see what _would_ happen.

Comment: @BrianCurtis Finally, at least hypothetically, what may _look like_ `_` chars. may be unrelated, similar-looking Unicode characters.

Comment: Hmm again... When I try entering -LiteralPath "\\?\$($PWD.ProviderPath)" into PowerShell, I get an error message: "The term '-LiteralPath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." All I know how to do is copy-paste strings of code, so I can't tell what switching calls would involve.

Comment: @BrianCurtis, what I meant was `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "\\?\$($PWD.ProviderPath)" -Filter *jpg`. Allow me to give you some general advice: It sounds like you need help with the fundamentals, which this site cannot provide. 
People trying to help you get embroiled in lengthy exchanges about incidental problems that could be avoided with a better grasp of the fundamentals.
I'm not trying to discourage you from asking questions, but please provide them as something at least approximating an [MCVE] or perhaps turn to colleagues for help.

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. Thanks for your efforts.